# Tense for something I did yesterday and also will be doing today

Tags: sentence-structure, syntax

My boss just asked me which task I was working on yesterday, and which one I will be working on today. I wanted to reply that I was working on the same task, but the sentence structure seemed awkward to me.

"Yesterday and today, I will be working on (task-name)"

What is the correct way to express this?

Comment: I've been working on the task since yesterday noon.

Comment: @HotLicks Or even better - *I'm continuing today with the same task I was on yesterday*.

Comment: What I would say if my boss asked me that, I'd just use present continuous: "I'm working on Task A." That covers yesterday and today quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English, one way of expressing this would be:

> I'm **continuing to work on** [task name].

You could also say:

> I've **been working on** [task name].

The former focuses a bit more on what you're doing today, the latter on what you did yesterday. However, in context, both formulations express that the task is ongoing, and would be understood as referring to both days.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the second way imply that I will be working on the task today? It seems to me as if it only expresses that I was working on the task before, but not that I will continue to work on it today.

Comment: As I said in the answer, in context it does carry that implication. *Have been working on* is different from *worked on*, after all.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on ______ since yesterday.

I started ____ yesterday and will likely be able to finish it today.

Answer (score 1):

Tense: **Present Perfect Continuous**

We form the Present Perfect Continuous like this:

I **have been working** on (task) since yesterday.
(= You started working on the task yesterday and you are still working on the same task)

We use the Present Perfect Continuous for an action or situation that begun in the past and continues until now:

You **have been sitting** there since five o'clock.
(=You started sitting there at five o'clock and you are still sitting there.)

Answer (score 0):

The single best verb tense in this situation is the present perfect continuous (**have been** + verbroot +**-ing**), which is used to describe actions that began in the past but have continued to the present moment and may not yet be completed.

http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/present-perfect-simple-and-present-perfect-continuous

http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect-continuous/

> I have been working on [task name].

or (using a contraction)

> I've been working on [task name].

so:

> Boss: What did you work on yesterday, and what will you be working on today?
>
> You: I've been working on [task name].

Note: *Strictly speaking*, if you say here that you "have been working on" a particular task, although it means that you already worked on the task yesterday and today, it does not necessarily mean that you will also continue to work on the same task later today. It just means that you started working on the task in the past, continued working on it until now, and, in this case, you have not yet completed it. (It could mean, as one example, that you will now do something else for the rest of the day and then resume working on the task next week.)

But apart from that very strict interpretation, in the particular scenario described in the original question if you only said "I have been working on [task name]" in response to your boss' question, your boss would reasonably conclude that your plan was to continue working on the same task later today.

Answer (score -2):

If you are not sure about Present Perfect Continuous here is a simple explanation with a video:https://szkolajezyk.pl/angielski-od-podstaw/present-perfect-continuous/ :)

Comment: -1 It is better to summarize the contents of a linked page, and **also** provide the link as a source. Should the linked page become unavailable, this answer will cease to have any value.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/136745)

Comment: Ok thanks, understood your opinion.